# Vue3 Issue when trying to create a component

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component

Trying to create a Vue3/Typescript component after upgrading from Vue2 but I get this error

ERROR in src/components/HelloWorld.vue:26:3
TS2769: No overload matches this call.

The last overload gave the following error.

```
Argument of type '{ name: string; props: { msg: { type: StringConstructor; required: false; }; }; data(): { name: string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentOptionsWithObjectProps<{ msg: { type: StringConstructor; required: boolean; }; }, unknown, unknown, {}, {}, ComponentOptionsMixin, ComponentOptionsMixin, Record<...>, string, any, any>'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'data' does not exist in type 'ComponentOptionsWithObjectProps<{ msg: { type: StringConstructor; required: boolean; }; }, unknown, unknown, {}, {}, ComponentOptionsMixin, ComponentOptionsMixin, Record<...>, string, any, any>'.
```

This is my simple Vue3 component, I don't know if I need to change tsconfig.json, or something else, I searched the questions but couldn't find anything.

```
<script lang="ts">

import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
    msg: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      name: 'Link'
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

If anyone can help me with this simple issue, I'm new to Vue3 and Typescript.

Comment: Check `tsconfig.json` and [recommended configuration](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#recommended-configuration)